# How do I dynamically append text to a Literal Class in asp.net instead of overwriting it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, text, append, literals

Using asp.net and vb, I am trying to dynamically add names to a Literal Class based on the date associated with the name.  I have created two Lists, listDate and listShiftName, with the dates and the associated names respectively.  Each name has a date associated with it, but there are more than one name for each date, so when I try to add them, it just overwrites each name so only the last name in the list appears.  Here is the code I have so far for adding the names:

```
For i = 0 To listDate.Count - 1
    If listDate(i) = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString Then
        litToday.Text = listShiftName(i)
    End If
Next i
```

What do I need to change in the line litToday.Text = listShiftName(i) to in order for it to append each name instead of overwriting the previous names with the last name in the list? I'm a N00B to asp.net and vb, so please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
`litToday.Text &= " " & listShiftName(i);`